# Electric field strength of a location infinitely close to its source

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, singularities, coulombs-law

The equation of the electric field strength is $$E = \frac{k Q_1}{r^2}, $$ but then wouldn't the strength of the field at a location infinitely close to the charge be infinity? If a neutral air molecule initially rested close to an unpowered anode, then the anode was powered and created a powerful electric field, wouldn't the neutral air molecule be ionized and the ionized air will be ejected along the field line in, for a short while, infinite speed?

Comment: Yes it would.  Forgive a snarky comment, but: so what?  Better:  It's impossible to get infinitely close to  a charge, so it is impossible to achieve a situation where the field would be infinite.  It never happens.

Comment: Note that getting infinitely close to a continuous charge _distribution_ does not necessarily result in an infinite electric field strength; for example, the field from an infinite sheet of charge is constant, no matter how close you get to it.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct. According to Coulomb's law, the electric field strength of a point charge goes to infinity when you approach the location of the point charge. This means, e.g., that for bringing two point charges (electrons) arbitrarily close to each other, you would need an arbitrarily high energy to do so. This is related to the fact that, classically, a point charge produces an electric field with infinite field energy. Thus there  must obviously occur a modification of the classical Coulomb law to avoid such infinities.

Comment: Either that or the charge has finite dimensions. We know that the proton has a radius of somewhat less than a femtometer ($10^{-15} m)$).

Comment: @my2cts - The proton has a finite radius, it consists of quarks, but the electron like other leptons (or quarks) are  thought to be point-like particles.

Comment: That just means that the radius is smaller than we can observe.